# SQL Azure Online Management Portal - What causes the 'Query Performance' Run Count to reset to zero?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We use an Azure SQL database and keep an eye on the Query Performance page of the Online Management Portal for expensive queries; i.e. this page:
http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-70-92-metablogapi/3058.image_5F00_60004D77.png

We have received outages in our service over the last week and this appears to coincide with the Run Count column resetting to zero for all of our queries.

My question is, what causes this Run Count to reset to zero, and could it also be causing outage to our Azure SQL database service? Is it the database being moved to a different node as we're hogging CPU?

Answer (score 3):

The "Query Performance" view in the portal is just a way presenting a query like the following, backed by data from the sql azure database engine.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS q
```

**[sys.dm_exec_sql_text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)**  and **[sys.dm_exec_query_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189741%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)** are both DMV's (**[Dynamic Management Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh441700.aspx)**),

DMV's are backed by in memory data structures ([source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh441700.aspx)), so if your databases get placed on new machines by the sql azure platform (for one of the many possible reasons not all bad) then the new machine obviously won't have any of the in memory data to feed the DMV's.

The fact that it's getting reset to zero is not definitive proof of an outage, if you have these sorts of questions you should open a ticket with support (there is a button in the portal).

Comment: So, as the run count is taken from a Dynamic Management View and the value is cumulative, presumably any of the following might cause the run count to be reset: SQL Server service restart, cluster node failover, database migration to a new cluster?